# Not receiving any output based on the user input I put in.

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

This is the code I have so far, I just tried to test it, by entering random charaters, to see if I get the correct if statement working, (also typed in quit).

However the nothing happens after I type in my input, any reasons as to why?

Thank you in advance.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

//==============================================================================        
        // Opening Message.
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome to the Theatre Booking System. (QUIT to exit)"
                + "\nWould you like to purchase tickets or list available seats?"
                + "(Purchase/List/Help)");
        scan.nextLine();
        String answer;

        answer = scan.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
//==============================================================================
        // Nested if statement.
        // First if statement.
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("purchase")) {
            // Code for purchase  
        } else {
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
                // Code for list   
            } else {
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
                    // Code for help
                } else {
                    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                        System.exit(-1);
                    } else {
                        do {
                            System.out.print("Sorry, incorrect input please enter"
                                    + " a valid input (Purchase/List/Help or QUIT to exit");
                            scan.nextLine();
                            count++;
                        } while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("purchase")
                                || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("list")
                                || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")
                                || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("help"));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should have used if-else-if ladder

Answer (score 1):

You have two `scan.nextLine()` statements, and you use the second one for input. So you need to press "Enter" first then the input followed by "Enter" again.

Also avoid nested-if, you can directly use the same `if` with multiple `else if` blocks